# How to find the image of the map $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{x}-(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{n}) \, \mathbf{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to find the image of the linear map $$\mathbf x \mapsto \mathbf{x}-(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{n}) \, \mathbf{n} = \mathbf x'$$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $\mathbf x$ is a (varying) vector in $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbf n$ is a given unit vector.

---

So far, by taking the cross product of both sides, I have obtained $$\mathbf x' \times \mathbf n = \mathbf x \times \mathbf n$$ where $\mathbf x'$ is the vector that $\mathbf x$ is mapped to.

This shows that for given $\mathbf x$, we have that $\mathbf x'$ lies on a line passing through $\mathbf x$ that is parallel to $\mathbf n$ (the same direction as $\mathbf n$). However, we don't know whether the entire line is contained in the image of the map so cannot leave it there.

I have also noticed that $(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{n}) \, \mathbf{n}$ is the component of $\mathbf x$ parallel to $\mathbf n$ so is the projection of $\mathbf x$ onto $\mathbf n$. This means that the image of the map is the perpendicular component of $\mathbf x$ with respect to $\mathbf n$.

I have these pieces of information but am not sure how to find a precise way to express exactly what subset of $\mathbb R^3$ is mapped to by this function.

Comment: "... the image of the map is the perpendicular component of $x$ with respect to $n$" --- _acu tetigisti_

Comment: Some additional questions that may help you clarify: (1) What is the nullspace of this map? (2) Does this map preserve any vectors?

Comment: This is the projection onto the plane that is the orthogonal compliment of the subspace generated by $n$. You can think of this as splitting the vector into a component parallel to $n$ and a second component in the orthogonal compliment $x'$ so that $x = x' + (x \cdot n)n$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{n})\mathbf{n}$ is $\mathbf{n}$ scaled by the component of $\mathbf{x}$ along $\mathbf{n}$, since $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector.

So, $\mathbf x \mapsto \mathbf{x}-(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{n}) \, \mathbf{n} = \mathbf x'$ projects $\mathbf{x}$ onto the plane through $O$ with normal vector $\mathbf{n}$, as illustrated:

[image: The vector x is projected onto the plane through O and with normal vector n by this transformation]

Therefore, the image of the transformation is the plane through $O$ with normal $\mathbf{n}$, which can be written $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(x)=x-(x.n)n,  f(x).n =0$ and if $ x.n=0, f(x)=x$ implies that the image is the orthogonal of $n$. $f$ is the orthogonal projection to the orthogonal of $n$.

Comment: Can you clarify what the notation $\langle f(x),n \rangle$ means?

Comment: the scalar product, $f(x).n$